# I want to provide user authentication through firebase but sign in page is accepting invalid inputs

Tags: html, css, firebase

```
<script>
      function save_user()
      {
     const uid = document.getElementById('user_id');
            const userpwd = document.getElementById('user_pwd');
            const btnregister=document.getElementById('btn-action');
            //btnregister.addEventListener('click', e=>
            //{
            const email=uid.value;
            const pass=userpwd.value;
            firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, pass).catch(function(error) {
    // Handle Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    console.log(error.Message);

});
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if(user) {
    window.location='userpage.html'; 
  }
});
            }
    </script>
<link href="page2.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
</head>
<body>
<div id="bg">
  <img src="images/5.jpg" alt="">
</div>
<div class="loginbox">
<img src="images/logo.jpg" class="user"/>
<form action="" method="post">
<p>Email</p>
<input type="text" name="" placeholder="Enter Email" id="user_id"/>
<p>Password</p>
<input type="password" name="" placeholder="......" id="user_pwd"/>
</br>
</br>
</br>
<input type="button" name="" value="Sign In" id="btn-action" onclick="save_user();">
<a href="#">Forgot Password</a>
<a href="Register.html">Register</a>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to provide user authentication through firebase but sign in page is accepting invalid inputs.How to print an error message if the user is not present in Firebase authentication?

Answer (score 0):

You may simple use html5 input regex to able correct email format into input:

```html
<form action="" method="post">
<input id="emailAddress" type="email"pattern="[a-z0-9._%+-]+@[a-z0-9.-]+\.[a-z]{2,4}$/">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer but my query was, whenever i am giving any random email id which has not been registered then also sign in page is accepting those email id.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You mean that : `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {...` has a `user` object even email is not a registered user email.

Comment: Yes, if I am giving any email id which is not registered in firebase when I am providing that email id in sign in page that also is taking me to next page .. I want that an error message should be displayed telling that email id doesn't exist

Comment: Thanks in advance

Comment: Check (console.log) user object, is it this user or ? ( maybe you need to sign out and set `null` to `user` object first.)